# Display items in list view based on group permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript

Is it possible to display the items in Sharepoint 2013 customized List based on the group permission? I have 3 groups in permission, i.e. Group A, Group B, Group C. Some people are in only 1 group and others could be in two or all three. The list has a Group Column. I'd like the list to only display the items that each personnel is in. Please help. thank you

UPDATE:

I tried the following code but it's not working. In the list I have a column titled "Group" with choices of Group A, Group B, and Group C. The group members are listed in Permission with type "SharePoint Group".  Please advise. Thank you

````
    <Where>
        <Membership Type ="CurrentUserGroup>
        <FieldRef Name ="Group"/>
        </Membership>
    </Where>
</Query>```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for your reference:

1.Apply item level permissions to the list for correct group.

2.Set Target Audiences on different view via choose the view you need>edit web part>Advanced>Target Audiences.

More information for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293#ID0EABAAA=SharePoint_Server_2010_-_2019